# Не могу попасть в админку Joomla

Tags: joomla

Не могу попасть на страницу авторизации для входа в админку сайта, то есть при переходе на www/site.ru/administrator выдает ошибку (Страница недоступна Сайт site.ru пока не может обработать этот запрос.
HTTP ERROR 500). Эта страница работала до того момента пока я не поменял в бд пароль от администратора. Подскажите как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: Как вариант. Вернуть всё как было. Надеюсь, если что, резервная копия есть.

Comment: Нет нету, неужели нет другого выхода?

Comment: Вряд ли. Если, конечно, у Вас этот пароль не был где-то записан в том виде, в котором он хранится в БД, а хранят CMS обычно не сам пароль, а просоленный хэш. А, вообще, только без обид, IT-шники делятся на 2 группы. Те, кто не делает резервные копии и то, кто уже их делает.

Comment: А если в бд удалить всех пользователе и добавить только одного? админка заработает?

Comment: Скорее всего Вы так окончательно положите сайт.

Comment: страница авторизации заработала. Теперь при вводе логина и пароля выдает (Предупреждение
Имя пользователя и пароль не совпадают или у вас ещё нет учётной записи на сайте)

Comment: Как вариант можно поставить чистую CMS на какой-нибудь XAMPP, перенёс туда всё с боевого сайта, а затем залил сайт с XAMPP на хостинг. **Предварительно создав резервные копии**. Если есть другая учётка с административными парвами, то можно ей воспользоаться для решения данной задачи. Это будет проще и быстрее.

Comment: По вашему описанию, очень похоже, что вы поменяли пароль  на подключение к БД в файле `configuration.php`? Потому, что в таком случае действительно будет на запрос возвращаться HTTP-ответ 500.

Comment: Нет я в самой бд в таблице user поменял пароль, теперь при авторизации выводит ошибку (Предупреждение
У вас нет доступа к панели управления сайтом.)